# Redirect Auditd.log data to rsyslog in RHEL-7

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, rhel7, auditd

I would like to redirect the `auditd` log data into `rsyslog` instead of *audit.log* file.

I see that by default in the */etc/audit/auditd.conf* the following line has been included to redirect it to

```
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Is it possible to redirect the Audit log to `syslog` or `rsyslog` on the same machine.

NOTE: I don't have any external log server at this point and would like to test this on the same instance of an RHEL Server where my application is running.

Any Assistance is greatly appreciated.

NOTE: My `rsyslog` Server and auditd logs are on the same server instance. RHEL-7 --> 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64

Thank you

Comment: auditd intentionally maintains its own log: it has tools to process these logs, such as `ausearch`. You should not redirect these to rsyslog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want audit logs to be written to `/var/log/messages`, you can achieve it by editing the `active` option value in the config file:

```
# vim /etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf
active = yes
direction = out
path = builtin_syslog
type = builtin
args = LOG_INFO
format = string
# systemctl reload auditd
```